# How to arrange this data in columns?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, formatting

I have a mysql database. In which there are 50 columns of detail.

```
Detail 1, Detail2, Detail3...... Detail50.
```

I have the website locally so i am scrapping from myself. The site is not in order no tags and names data is just in form of text line by line, so this was the only option to take what i get line by line and save to DB. So every line gets a column from 1-50....

Some pages have 10 columns other have 50 and the data is in no order now i have the DB,how can i sort them any suggestion ,idea is welcome.

This image will make it more clear:

[image]

So You can see Sometimes its Inner Diameter in Detail4 and sometime in 1, these are just examples i would have hard coded but there are too many possibilities, but the repeating words all have the same staring name just values different .Any chance to atleast make 50 % of the data in order the ones with same 4-5 starting words like

```
part,inner,diameter,oil filter etc.
```

Any suggestion or ideas can it be done in mysql or C# code.....
Thank you

Comment: @COLDTOLD i will if i know where to start with !

Comment: I thing before you even start you have to undestand what information must be in what column for instance diameter 1 in detail 1, diameter 2 in detail 2 and so on then just sort it and bind it to specific column

Comment: @COLDTOLD it does not matter what goes in what diameter can be in detail 1 , 2, 3, or 4 ..But once its in detail4 all should be in detail 4 similarly for all others.. As i said i would have hard coded like if it ("diameter") insert to detail 1 etc... but there are many many possibilities of words so that is no option,its just 50 columns here but if i change product types new set of words come in like oil filter etc..so i need something dynamic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your approach is totally wrong, but if you want to go this way, just make a table with two columns `'id'` and `'details'` ... make an insert for each column for the specific product ID.
After that you can use a `SELECT` like that:

`select SUBSTRING(details, 14) from products where details like 'Inner Diameter%' and id = 'my_product_id';`

Comment: `insert into newtable id, innerdiam values(select id, SUBSTRING(details1, 14) from products where details1 like 'Inner Diameter%' and id = 'my_product_id';)` create a new table and put the values in the correct columns in that, style executing something like this for each  details1..50 ... diferent approach if you like to try

Comment: The first approach shown in the answer allows you to have as many values as you need for a product ... no need to have fixed count of 50 columns

Comment: Is there any sql query to get all the unique values from the table?which will give me all possible terms ? But with substring something like select distinct(substring(columns,16)) from all table?

Comment: `insert into newtable id, details values (select id, details1 from products;)` .. one statement for each column 1..50 will transform your table to a new table with one colum ...this will allow you to manipulate your table much easier

Comment: after that you can use something like that: `select distinct SUBSTRING(details, 16) from newtable`